# Increment Shopping cart item quantity using session

Tags: php, ajax, json

I know that my question could be very similar to anothers in Stackoverflow. I have found some similar questions but actually I couldn't get the right solution for my problem;

I am writing shopping cart using Sessions and ajax-json.
 My products
 structure is a bit complicated. It has name, size, type, colour and a
 specific price for each type and size. The main point is that I can't
 increment the item quantity if the name, size, type, color and price are
 the same, if I'm adding the same product.  Here is my code. I think I
 am writing right, but I can't understand what is the problem.
 Actually it increments the item quantity, but just one time, and when
 I am checking the array, it's item quantity has not been incremented.

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData'], true);
    $pr_type = $data['pr_type'];
    $pr_size = $data['pr_size'];
    $pr_link = $data['pr_link'];
    $pr_color = $data['pr_color'];
    $pr_price = $data['pr_price'];

    $products_s = $this->getSession()->get('prof_cart');
    $product = array();

    if (empty($products_s)) {
        $products_s = array();
    } else {
        $products_s = $products_s;
    }

    $products = Model::factory('Client_Product')->getProductById($pr_link);
    $type = Model::factory("Client_Product")->getProductTypeByLink($pr_type);
    $size = Model::factory("Client_Product")->getProductSizeById($pr_size);
    if ($pr_type != 'undefined') {
        $product['type'] = $type[0]['title'];
    } else {
        $product['type'] = "";
    }
    $isCreate = true;

    foreach ($products_s as $id) {
        if ($id['price'] == $pr_price &&
                $id['title'] == $products[0]['title'] &&
                $id['size'] == $size[0]['size'] &&
                $id['type'] == $type[0]['title']) {
            $id['quant']++;
            $isCreate = false;
        }
    }

    if ($isCreate) {
        $product['quant'] = 1;
        $product['size'] = $size[0]['size'];
        $product['title'] = $products[0]['title'];
        $product['price'] = $pr_price;            
        $product['color'] = $pr_color;
        array_push($products_s, $product);
    }

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($products_s as $id) {
        $sum += $id['price'] * $id['quant'];
    }

    //echo $sum;

    echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($products_s);
   echo "</pre>";

    $this->getSession()->set('prof_cart', $products_s);

    $this->getSession()->set('prof_sum', $sum);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase quantity in your main product array like below.

```
foreach ($products_s as $key => $id) {
    if ($id['price'] == $pr_price &&
            $id['title'] == $products[0]['title'] &&
            $id['size'] == $size[0]['size'] &&
            $id['type'] == $type[0]['title']) {
        $products_s[$key]['quant']++;
        $isCreate = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    foreach ($products_s as $id) {
    if ($id['price'] == $pr_price &&
            $id['title'] == $products[0]['title'] &&
            $id['size'] == $size[0]['size'] &&
            $id['type'] == $type[0]['title']) {
        $id['quant'] = $id['quant']++;
        $isCreate = false;
    }
}
```